# unable to search for lookup objects using lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am unable to search for lookup objects using `lightning:recordEditForm`:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Contact">
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone"/>
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" />
   <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

As you can see in the attached image that spinner is continuously loading and I'm unable to search for existing account.

[image]

My component is embedded in visualforce page, so that I can use this in lightning and classic both. But unable to fetch lookup records. Is there any workaround for this.

Comment: you supply also recordId or other fields? please show us all of your code

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm):

> The lookup type is supported in Lightning Experience only. When used in the mobile app, the lookup type is rendered as an input text field.

It appears that you're trying to use this in a normal Lightning App. This won't work, as a Lightning App is *not* the Lightning Experience.

Comment: well, the OP mentioned that the loading icon is displayed (I've the same issue actually), and it's not a simple input text field. I understand your point, but it looks like a bug